# CSS - Website won't center in browser

Tags: html, css, center

No matter what I do, I cant get my website to center when looking at it in the browser :/. I've looked all over google/youtube and tried everything. Getting very annoyed with it at this point.

Heres the code:

```css
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>01_Home</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<!-- Save for Web Styles (01_Home.psd) -->
<style type="text/css">
<!--

#Table_01 {
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 1600px;
 
}

#id01-Home {
 position:relative;
 width:1600px;
 height:8226px;
 margin:0 auto;
 }

-->
</style>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- End Save for Web Styles -->
</head>
<body style="background-color:#FFFFFF; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0px;">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (01_Home.psd) -->
<div id="Table_01">
 <div id="id01-Home">
  <img src="images/01_Home.jpg" width="1600" height="8226" alt="">
 </div>
</div>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Google works for me...https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=css%20centering&oq=css%20centering&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5752j0j7

Comment: div  's  height and width are large that's why it's not in center .. tell me what exactly is your question .

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you apply the following styles to your BODY tag:

```
  text-align:center;
```

And then create an outer container (say DIV.container) with the following styles:

```
 text-align:left;
 width: 50%;
 margin: 0 auto;
```

Remove all other styles until you have that working then re-add any styles that you require.

Here is an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/wshobaqh/
(sorry, I can't work out how to apply a snippet into SO)

Answer (score 0):

For screens wider than 1600px (which seem to be your only concern) you can simply add `margin: 0 auto;`  to `#Table_01` to center it. But below that width you'll need a completely different approach.

Details depend on your actual content and layout which is not visible in your code - or is that image really your only content? If yes, I'd suggest to use percentage values for width (like 100% width for the image and its parent elements) to be able to view the whole image on smaller screens.